# Why does this ReviewApi giving problem while working with Dagger Hilt?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

See this error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.test.consumer.service.api.review.ReviewApi cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements testApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      com.test.consumer.service.api.review.ReviewApi is injected at
          com.test.consumer.service.data.review.ReviewRepository(reviewApi)
      com.test.consumer.service.data.review.ReviewRepository is injected at
          com.test.consumer.app.user.reviews.ReviewViewModel(repository)
      com.test.consumer.app.user.reviews.ReviewViewModel is injected at
          com.test.consumer.app.user.reviews.ReviewViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.test.consumer.service.testApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.test.consumer.service.testApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.test.consumer.service.testApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC
```

]

So, the flow is like this:

1. interface ReviewApi ->
2. class ReviewRepository @Inject constructor(
   private val reviewApi: ReviewApi
   )
3. @HiltViewModel
   class ReviewViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: ReviewRepository) : BaseViewModel() {
4. Will implement @AndroidEntryPoint in Activity, but before that only I'm not able to sync the project, also tried adding in Activity, but still same issue!!

Edit:

Added some more code:

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient): Retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(URLConstants.API_BASE)
            .client(client).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        okHttpClientBuilder.readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClientBuilder.connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClientBuilder.writeTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        val logger =
            HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                } else {
                    level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
                }
            }

        okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(logger)
        return okHttpClientBuilder.build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideReviewApi(retrofit: Retrofit): ReviewApi = retrofit.create(ReviewApi::class.java)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideReviewRepository(reviewApi: ReviewApi) = ReviewRepository(reviewApi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to provide retrofit interfaces(any interface or any thrid-party library classes) you need to use modules and @Provide Annotation

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingleComponent::class)
object AppModule{
@Provides
fun provideBaseUrl() = Constants.BASE_URL

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideOkHttpClient() = 
    OkHttpClient
        .Builder()
        .build()
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, BASE_URL:String): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build()

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit) = retrofit.create(ReviewApi::class.java)  //Here you have provided the interface and can be injected in anywhere in your Module
```

Comment: Obviously I did that, see I added that code also now. Can you please check one more time, if u solve the issue, I'll surely upvote and accept ur invitation. Thanks!

Comment: Your Module looks good, are you getting the same error or any other error now??

Comment: Ok I think I found the problem, but still not able to solve it. Can you just tell me one things? I want my application class object in my module itself.

Comment: basically I want to remove this dependency from constructor: class ApplicationModule(application: TestApplication) {

Comment: You can use `@ApplicationContext` if you need context as dependency everywhere in your project, and also make sure to create `@HiltAndroipApp` class too

Comment: Can you please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70838081/how-to-get-myapplication-class-object-in-dagger-hilt-architecture-in-android

Comment: Any time Brother!!