# How to get MyApplication class object in dagger hilt architecture in Android?

Tags: android

Basically I'm migrating from dagger to hilt. So I must need to remove this argument `class ApplicationModule(application: MyApplication) {` So, there are few places that I want to pass application class object from my dagger hilt module. few are 3rd part library as well.

Code:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class ApplicationModule(application: MyApplication) {

    private val application: MyApplication = application

....

@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGoogleSignInClient(): GoogleSignInClient {
        val mGoogleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(application.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        return GoogleSignIn.getClient(application, mGoogleSignInOptions)
    }
```

like this many places are there. So how can I achieve this?

EDIT:

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserService(): NewUserService {
        return NewUserService(application)
    }
```

---

```
class NewUserService @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext context: Context) : BaseServices(context) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Hilt's `@ApplicationContext` annotation to substitute your `application` with the application context. Make the following change:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGoogleSignInClient(@ApplicationContext applicationContext: Context): GoogleSignInClient {
        val mGoogleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(applicationContext.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        return GoogleSignIn.getClient(applicationContext, mGoogleSignInOptions)
    }
```

To address your further question.
When you are providing your class within the module, you do not need to also instruct Dagger to @Inject it. Your code will be like so:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserService(@ApplicationContext context: Context): NewUserService {
        return NewUserService(context)
    }
```

And your class:

```
class NewUserService (context: Context) : BaseServices(context)
```

Constructor injection is useful in the case where Dagger already knows how to provide your dependency classes. For example you have the following:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMyClass(@ApplicationContext applicationContext: Context): MyClass {
        val someField = funToReturnValue(applicationContext)

        return MyClass.initialise(someField)
    }
```

Then when you have another class that needs `MyClass`, you can just use constructor injection because Dagger already knows how to construct MyClass. You would do:

```
class MySecondClass @Inject constructor(val myClass: MyClass)
```

Comment: got it, just one last doubt before accepting your answer. I edited code. What about that?

Comment: You don't need to `@Inject` your constructor if you are providing it in your module

Answer (score 0):

Do This

```
InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class ApplicationModule() {


....

@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGoogleSignInClient(@ApplicationContext application): GoogleSignInClient {
        val mGoogleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(application.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        return GoogleSignIn.getClient(application, mGoogleSignInOptions)
    }

@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserService(@ApplicationContext application): NewUserService {
        return NewUserService(application)
    }
```

Now your service class will become like this

```
class NewUserService (context: Context) : BaseServices(context) {
```